# Inverse of 1D vector Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have 1D vector. For example: `y=[0.2 0.9 1.0 1.0]`. I can plot it with `plot(y)` to get a graph of `y(x)` where `x` values are just indices `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Now, instead of `x` values being just indices, I want to map them to `[0,1]` range: `x = linspace(0,1,length(y))`. I get: `x=[0 0.3333 0.6667 1.000]`.

I can now make a graph with `plot(x,y)`:

[image]

Now, however, I want an inverse graph, so I make a plot with `plot(y,x)`:
[image]

I want to be able to now use `plot(x)` to get the same shape as above. However, if I use `plot(x)`, as expected, I just get a straight line.

How to transform `x` in such a way that `plot(x)` will give the same shape as `plot(y,x)`?

Upd.: If I try just `1./x`:
[image]

Comment: Why don't you want to use `plot(y,x)`? I almost never use `plot(x)`, even when I want integer indices (I'd use `plot(1:numel(x),x)`), because of controlabillity of the function.

Comment: @Adriaan Because I am not going to plot it. The plot was used only as an example, because I don't know how to better explain what I mean by "inverse of 1D vector". In general, I need to use is as a transformation vector and multiply it element-wise with another 1D vector.

Comment: Then `1./x` would suffice. The plot just creates confusion, since the `x` locations of corresponding `y` values also get changed (e.g. the 2nd value of the first plot is at `x==1/3`, whereas in the second plot it's at `x==0.9`), which means you need 2 numbers per point, as opposed to the single one you're apparently after, judging your comment.

Comment: @Adriaan if I just get `1./x`, this gives me completely different y-axis values from the ones I am looking for (added to the original question).

Comment: `fliplr` for row-vectors then? That's not the inverse, but rather 'read in opposite direction'. The images don't help a thing; all they do is confuse me. Can you just show in numbers what you want; i.e. first your `x,y` pair as you have it now, then what you get using your method, and finally what you want to obtain? Just in numbers?

Comment: @Valeria can you please explain what the array `y` should be to get the result you want?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to find a solution, so for anybody who also need its:

```
x = linspace(0,1,length(y));
% not needed in this toy example, but can be required for a bigger vector:
[y_unique, idx] = unique(y);  
inv_y = interp1(y_unique,x(idx),x);
```

Comment: Note that this is only possible if `y` is strictly monotoníc. The `unique` removes duplicate points, making it applicable to any monotonic function.